# Units of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose you have the system $\bf x' = \bf Ax$, where $\bf x$ is a vector and $\bf A$ is a matrix. What are the units of the eigenvalues of $\bf A$? I think they should be $1/t$ but I'm not sure how to verify this. Can you give me a starting point?

Comment: Where did $t$ come into the Question?  Pure numbers are "dimensionless"; they have no units in the sense of measurement.

Comment: This belongs to Physics.SE; There are no units of measurement in eigenvalues.

Comment: What's a unit?$\ $

Comment: TIL mathematicians have a really difficult time grasping the notion of "unit"...

Answer (score 6):

Your intuition is correct, they should be 1/(the dimension of what you are taking the derivative with respect to).  If your derivative is with respect to time, then it should be $1/t$.  If your derivative is with respect to something unitless, the eigenvalue will be unitless, too.  Write it as $\frac {dx}{dt}=Ax$  The units of $A$ are then $1/t$ and so the eigenvalues will be, too.  If you are taking derivatives with respect to time, maybe the question belongs at physics.

Comment: This is not sensible. Whatever units you want to attach to the equation, so that a derivative with respect to time has a measurable interpretation, eigenvalues are by definition pure numbers.  We cannot say $Ax = \lambda x$ defines an eigenvalue if the value of $\lambda$ is something other than a scalar.

Comment: @hardmath: I believe you can.  A matrix can have units, for example the inertia matrix of an object has units $m\cdot \ell^2$  The eigenvalue equation shows the eigenvalue has the same units.  As A in this problem has units of inverse time, so must $\lambda$  The units will tell me how the numeric entries in the matrix change if I change units.  So if we change the units of time from seconds to minutes, the numeric entries in A need to be multiplied by $60$

Answer (score 2):

The unit of the eigenvalue is the same as the unit of the matrix itself. That becomes evident from the eigenvalue equation $A v = \lambda v$.

So if your matrix $A$ has unit 1/s (I assume in your case the dash denotes time derivative), the eigenvalue $\lambda$ has unit 1/s as well.

The unit of the eigenvectors on the other hand is undetermined - it can be anything you chose.